# AngularJS: how do i lazyload/register a provider?

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I know you can register a controller dynamically after the app is bootstrapped via the `$controllerProvider` via

```
$controllerProvider.register('controllername', function () {
    // controller stuff here
});
```

a service i found could be registered via $provide

```
$provide.service('servicename', function () {
    // service stuff here
});
```

but I can't seem to find how to register a provider in a lazyload way.

Answer (score 0):

A technique I first saw [here](https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers) involves a `config` function that "steals" the necessary providers.

Explanation:

The important providers (e.g. directives, route, controller) are only available in the config phase. If you want to add something later on, you will have to create a config function that stores the reference to the desired provider for later use (since it is not expressively permitted or forbidden, I call it "stealing"). Then a custom service that knows about the "stolen" references will use them to register whatever is needed later on.

My own effort to lazy-load Angular stuff with RequireJS is [here](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) and is using the same principle.

Comment: but that is already what i'm using, i 'steal' those providers for controllers and directives and all, the one thing can't find is which one (and what syntax) i need to provide a provider, jeez naming conflicts... you can have services, factories and providers, and i know how to register the services and factories but can't get a provider to work

Comment: I am sorry - I did not understand your original question. However, wouldn't stealing `$provide` and calling `$provide.provider()` lazily work? Haven't tried it, just wondering... The problem I see here (is this your problem?) is that you can not *use* the lazilly created provider *itself*. You can use (inject) the service it provides, but you cannot inject the provider.

Comment: i feel stupid :p just found my issue, i had a typo in provider... correct syntax is $provide.provider('name', function(){});